# How to setup Socket.io for listen separate pages with Express NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have the next `server.js` file structure, where I have two pages and only for last `/chat` page I need to implement the event listener by Socket.io library:

```
'use strict'

const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const index = require('./routes/index');
const chat = require('./routes/chat');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/chat', chat);

// sockets.io code part start...
app.use((req, res, next) => { 
    res.locals['socketio'] = io; 
    next(); 
});
// sockets.io code part finish...

const port = process.env.API_PORT || 8989;
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

What I get by this structure? My `server` listen all enters on the site by `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000/chat`, that is a wrong. So, I think I need to implement my part of code that responce for handling `sockets.io` events in the specific route `/chat`...

I had the next `chat.js` file in my routes system:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
    next();
});

router.route('/chat')
    .get((req, res) => {
        let messages = [];
        let userCounter = 0;
        let users = [];

        const io = res.locals['socketio'];
        io.on('connect', (socket) => {
            console.log('Connection established!');
            socket.on('new user', (message) => {
                userCounter++;
                users.push(userCounter)
                console.log('New user is in! Count of users online:', users)
            });

            socket.emit('new connect', messages);

            socket.on('message data', (message) => {
                console.log(message);
                messages.push(message);
                io.emit('New message:', message);
            });
        });
        res.json('Hello on the Chatpage!');
    });

module.exports = router;
```

How can I implement sockets.io in my case only for `/chat` page without global invoke of `socket.io library` in `server` file or it's impossible? I need any help...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update your code accordingly:

```
    // Declare socket.io
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);

    // Set middleware
    app.use((req, res, next)=>{ res.locals['socketio'] = io; next(); });

    // Later in a chat route
    router.get('/chat', (req, res, next)=>{
      const io = res.locals['socketio']
    });
```

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not help.. I also update my code for you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to upgrade the HTTP connection to a websocket connection, so you still need socket.io in the main page...